# ValueError: Max Value is 52 - Issue with destination excel file

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, valueerror

So I have hit a wall. I am trying to use Openpyxl to move date from one excel sheet to another, and get his error. For the life of me I can not figure out what I am doing wrong, or a work around to fix it. It seems to be an issue with the destination workbook I am loading. When I use a new empty file it works fine. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  File "C:\Users\ron\Documents\Python\AndreaMilage2.py", line 43, in <module>
    dest_wb = load_workbook('Destination.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\ron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\ron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 280, in read
    self.read_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\ron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 255, in read_worksheets
    charts, images = find_images(self.archive, rel.target)
  File "C:\Users\ron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\drawings.py", line 27, in find_images
    drawing = SpreadsheetDrawing.from_tree(tree)
  File "C:\Users\ron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\ron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\ron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  [Previous line repeated 4 more times]
  File "C:\Users\ron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "C:\Users\ron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\drawing\text.py", line 115, in __init__
    self.pitchFamily = pitchFamily
  File "C:\Users\ron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 108, in __set__
    super(Min, self).__set__(instance, value)
  File "C:\Users\ron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 87, in __set__
    raise ValueError('Max value is {0}'.format(self.max))
ValueError: Max value is 52
```

```
~~~
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
trips = int(input('How many trips?'))

#Load Workbooks and read sheets
src_wb = load_workbook('Source.xlsx')
dest_wb = load_workbook('Destination.xlsx')

src_sheet = src_wb["Trips"]
dest_sheet = dest_wb["Mileage"]


#Importing Date
for i in range(1,trips+1):
    dest_sheet.cell(row=i+7, column=1).value = src_sheet.cell(row=i+23, column=5).value
#Importing Start
for i in range(1,trips+1):
    dest_sheet.cell(row=i+7, column=2).value = src_sheet.cell(row=i+23, column=3).value
#Importing End
for i in range(1,trips+1):
    dest_sheet.cell(row=i+7, column=4).value = src_sheet.cell(row=i+23, column=4).value
#Importing Notes
for i in range(1,trips+1):
    dest_sheet.cell(row=i+7, column=5).value = src_sheet.cell(row=i+23, column=9).value
#Importing Miles
for i in range(1,trips+1):
    dest_sheet.cell(row=i+7, column=10).value = src_sheet.cell(row=i+23, column=2).value


src_wb.save('Source.xlsx')
dest_wb.save('Destination.xlsx')
~~~
```

Comment: Can you shows the code?

Comment: Added the code above.